# Publishing GeoTiffs with Geoserver - ColorPalette with Alpha

Tags: geoserver

I want to publish rasterdata (Geotiffs) with GeoServer. The resulting image from WMS is shown in Grayscale, but actually it is an RGB-Image.
gdalinfo:

```
P:\OSGeo4W\bin>P:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalinfo  Q:\data\tif\pic.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Q:\data\tif\pic.tif
Size is 4523, 4522
Coordinate System is:
LOCAL_CS["DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 3",
    GEOGCS["DHDN",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["unretrievable - using WGS84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","31467"],
    UNIT["metre",1]]
Origin = (3532474.929505631800000,5367000.280343170300000)
Pixel Size = (0.333485342299112,-0.333485342299112)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2012/05/08 11:38:04
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=WGEO 5.0 WGEO BASIS
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=200
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=200
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 3532474.930, 5367000.280)
Lower Left  ( 3532474.930, 5365492.260)
Upper Right ( 3533983.284, 5367000.280)
Lower Right ( 3533983.284, 5365492.260)
Center      ( 3533229.107, 5366246.270)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Overviews: 2262x2261, 1131x1131, 566x566
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
  Overviews of mask band: 2262x2261, 1131x1131, 566x566
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 0,0,0,255
    1: 128,0,0,255
    2: 0,128,0,255
    3: 128,128,0,255
    4: 0,0,128,255
   ...
  253: 255,0,255,255
  254: 0,255,255,255
  255: 255,255,255,255
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  Overviews: 2262x2261, 1131x1131, 566x566
```

I think the problem is the Alpha-Channel. Without this Channel, the resulting image/colors are correct. 
I'm using the default style "raster" from Geoserver.

Answer (score 1):

This one has been answered on the GeoServer ML:

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Publishing-GeoTiffs-ColorPalette-with-Alpha-td5128601.html

> You are right, I believe we don't (currently) support this kind of 
>   GeoTiff in GeoServer.
>
> I would probably try to select the first band and see what happens, 
>   going by memory I am not sure we should retain the colormap atatched 
>   to it.

Simone.